# Converting OpenCV grayscale Mat to Caffe blob

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe

I've been [following an example](https://github.com/jyegerlehner/caffe/blob/nat_img_autoenc_parallel/tools/prop-patches.cpp) I was referred to on how to convert an OpenCV `Mat` into a Caffe object I could make predictions from. From what I understand, the first section scales the image and then initialises the caffe class `TransformationParameter`:

```
const float img_to_net_scale = 0.0039215684;
TransformationParameter input_xform_param;
input_xform_param.set_scale( img_to_net_scale );
DataTransformer<float> input_xformer( input_xform_param, TEST );
```

Then, the OpenCV Mat "patch" is converted into "input_blob". I've changed this part because I've loaded in my image in grayscale instead of colour.

```
cv::Mat patch = cv::imread( input_file_str, CV_LOAD_IMAG_GRAYSCALE  );
Blob<float> input_blob;
input_blob.Reshape(1, patch.channels(), patch.rows, patch.cols );
input_xformer.Transform( patch, &input_blob );
```

Finally, I'm not too sure what this section does - if I already have my OpenCV Mat converted to a Caffe blob, why do I need to push back on the "input" vector and pass it to the net? Can't I pass input_blob directly into the net to get my prediction back?

```
std::vector<Blob<float>*> input;
input.push_back( &input_blob );

std::vector<Blob<float>*> output = net->Forward( input );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `push_back` your `input_blob` in order to pass it to `net` since `net` is expecting its input as a *`std::vector`* of `Blobs` (in principle, there may be `net`s that need more than a single input blob to produce output).
Note that you are not copying `input_blob` into the input vector, but rather passing a pointer to it.

Comment: Thanks so much! By the way, if I wanted to perform the scaling step myself on the Mat object should I just multiple the image by 0.0039215684?

Comment: @JackSimpson I'm not 100% sure. you should be able to check it yourself in debug mode.